# How to call multiple ajax at same time (and get results asychronous) in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

I want to send multiple ajax calls in ReactJS, and I wonder if the code is executed in order. Will the second ajax call be sent only after the first ReactJS component is rendered?

```
var firstAJAX = React.createClass({
  componentWillMount: function() {
    this.state = {list: []};
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/someurl',
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({list: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error('url', status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    })
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
             {something}
        </div>
    )
  }
})
ReactDOM.render(<firstAJAX />,
  document.getElementById('div')
);

var secondAJAX = React.createClass({
   //similar code with different url from firstAJAX
});
```

I want to handle multiple document elements with the results got from ajax. How to make the **send 1 ajax->render->send 1 ajax->render->...** become **send multiple ajaxs -> render -> render...**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you add the following code after your `var secondAJAX = ...` declaration, the 2nd ajax call would happen after the first one rendered.

```
ReactDOM.render(<secondAJAX />,
  document.getElementById('div')
);
```

I don't know what you're hoping to accomplish with this question, but you probably don't want to be doing things this way.

Comment: How to send 2nd ajax before the first ajax got results?

Answer (score 0):

I think your way is to use [container components](https://medium.com/@learnreact/container-components-c0e67432e005#.js9axccqf) pattern. In this case you can run two requests for `firstAJAX` & `secondAJAX` in container and define behaviour of child elements as you want